# How can I edit one byte randomly in a pcap file in a loop and still have it be valid?

Tags: python, networking, binary, pcap

I am automating an endpoint which requires a new pcap every time.

Rather than get a whole mess of them to download, I want to slightly modify my one pcap every time, so it's a unique pcap every time I use it.

I tried just adding random binary to the end, but that makes it no longer a valid pcap.

Is there a way, without using some third party library, I can adjust one byte randomly each time within the pcap to make it unique?

Comment: You will need to recalculate any checksums in whatever protocols are in use.

Comment: @RonMaupin How about if I just append a simple ICMP request or something each time? Do you know what that would look like?

Comment: You can't just change stuff like that. You have to know what is there, and you need to adjust for any changes you make.

Comment: If it is just necessary that the pcap file is changed you could change the timestamp of the last packet, i.e. `ts_usec` in the record header. That's a bit of effort to find the exact position (look at the [pcap file format](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat)) but then you can arbitrary change it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich great thought!

Do you know of an easy way to index into that with Python? Ideally it wouldn't rely on some third party library, but I understand if I need to.

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning: I don't know of a specific package which does this already for you. But the pcap format is fairly simple, i.e. a fixed size global header followed by  the records where each record has a fixed size record header which includes the length of the following variable sized payload. See [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) for the details.